# Return to previous tab when activity is destroyed

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I have 2 activities

1. MainActivity
2. ProjectActivity

MainActivity has 3 tabs (fragments)

1. Frag1
2. Frag2
3. Frag3

When I go to Frag2 and click 'Add' button from action bar, ProjectActivity is started. In Project Activity when I click on 'Cancel' button I am starting MainActivity again. But now when MainActivity is started it shows Frag1.

How can change my code to show Frag2, as user was on Frag2 previously?

I use this simple code to start the MainActivity when cancel button is clicked.

```
intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not restart the main activity.  Use `finish()` instead. That takes you back to the original `MainActivity` instead of creating a new one.  This is the same behavior you get from the back button.

See [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) for a more in-depth view of the back stack.

Comment: First time i've seen this. A bunch of people had solutions like the guy below you, but this is definitely the way it is supposed to be done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a variable to save the current tab and update in onPause(). Also check the same variable in onResume() and set the current tab accordingly.